# 85 Suzuki Samurai - Engine sometimes stalls, and hard to start when warm. Probably electrical problem

Tags: ignition, suzuki, ignition-coil, stall, hot-start

I'm having a problem with my car. Sometimes when engine is warm, it will strugle to start (starter runs fine, but no ignition). It also happens (rarely) that the engine just dies while driving. It seems very random - usually it will start immediately. When running, everything is 100% normal, no struggle/hesitation, idling just fine.

I think it's some kind of electrical problem (since starting fluid does not help).

It's definitely not the battery (always normal voltage). It's fine, and the stereo (custom built, connected directly to battery) works fine always, even when engine dies.

I already replaced the spark plugs.

The voltmeter in the dashboard gives a low reading, as visualized here:  [xxxO------xxx] (the O represent the needle, so just round around good and red area. Usually a little more at the yellow area. I guess this is an indicator of a problem.

When I meassure the voltage of the wire that goes to the Ignition coil, it reads 12.4V, so that should be good. But if I connect that wire to the ignition coil and meassure, it reads 11.4. Not sure if that's normal?

Any suggestions on where I should connect my multimeter, and what normal readings should be?

Comment: More than likely it is the distributor or ignition module, had one close to that year with exact symptom, Installed a new distributor and solved it.

Comment: Actually, I already bought a new ignition coil, but the engine is not running correctly with it. The same system as a "defective" ignition coil. So I put the old one back in... Any way to test the distributor?

Comment: No good way to test since it fails after reaching a certain temperature, hard to repeat this during a test.

Comment: I would also check fuel pressure.